# extremely Inconsistent AWS remote database query times,

Tags: c#, sql, amazon-web-services, entity-framework-6

I am querying for values from a database in AWS sydney, (I am in new zealand), using stopwatch i measured the query time, it is wildly inconsistent, sometimes in the 10s of milliseconds and sometimes in the hundreds of milliseconds, for the exact same query. I have no idea why.

```
Var device = db.things.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ThingName == model.thingName);
```

things table only has 5 entries, I have tried it without the asqueryable and it seems to make no difference. I am using visual studio 2013, entity framework version 6.1.1

EDIT:
Because this is for a business, I cannot put a lot of code up, another time example is that it went from 34 ms to 400 ms

thanks

Comment: You have not provided enough information to advise on. Timing a single query is not a good way to measure a database. You need to time a large set of queries with timings that match real world for your setup. IMHO a single query that is sometimes 20ms and sometimes 200ms is nothing to worry about. It is when 1000 queries averaged are sporatic... You also do not mention anything about your setup which can affect your numbers more than actual DB queries.

Comment: Hello, can you please elaborate on what you mean by setup?, thanks

Comment: What are you running everything on in AWS. What instance size, etc.

Comment: I dont have access to AWS account, its T2.micro

Comment: T2.micro are instances that are considered exceptions. Basically low numbers on CPU, disk I/O and network. You share all resources with other VMs on the same host. For T2 this means your performance is affected by others. Note: This is not true for other instance types which actually allocate resources to instances. Although many people run databases on T2 instances, I would not.

Answer (score 1):

This can be related to cold-warm query execution.

The very first time any query is made against a given model, the Entity Framework does a lot of work behind the scenes to load and validate the model. We frequently refer to this first query as a "cold" query. Further queries against an already loaded model are known as "warm" queries, and are much faster.

You can find more information about this in the following article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx

One way to make sure this is the problem is to write a Stored Procedure and get data by it(using Entity Framework) to see if the problem is in the connection or in the query(Entity Framework) itself.